# Trouble Selecting Primary Key

Tags: sql

I am working on a database which stores information about loan numbers. I would like to use these as the primary key, but when discussing the design of this project with the director he stated that it will be possible for this data to be repeated because the data in relation to it in other may be different.

An example without getting into the weeds would be that the gov't decides to place a second claim on the same address and loan number for a different amount of money. This would be on top of the previous claim which is already input into the database.

What options do I have here? I would want a query for a specific loan to bring up all information for that loan number which is why I would want it to pull the primary key from that column.

The only thing I can think to do is to make the table even larger by creating categories for new claims on the same property. The problem is the name of the claim is going to create duplicate column headers...then I would have to figure that out and change the process that they are using for data entry.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Information on multiple claims for a single claim number belong in a different table if you want a normalized schema.

Comment: First of all, it's almost always a bad idea to use real data as Primary Key.  Just add a separate (preferably int) column with unique numbers that is either auto-generated or use any other method for generating unique IDs.

Comment: You can use the loan number in an index -- this would speed searches on loan numbers.  Just don't make it a distinct index.  Create another internal ID for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you have a table that holds the loan numbers and a table of claims and each loan number can have multiple claims, using a foreign key? Why does the loan number need to be a primary key ?

Comment: It does not need to be necessarily, I was trying to utilize it as a primary key because the numbers are unique to each loan and information regarding the loan. It seems as though my only option is to use an auto generated column of indexed numbers. The problem with having a table of claims is that they do not currently use a unique identifier for those claims either. They just populate new dates and dollar amount information with the loan number repeated in their data. According to the information I have been given there is not a unique number given by the government agency we work with.

Comment: But if you dump the claims in a table using the loan number as a foreign key then why do the claims need a unique number in the data ? (Other than the generic id you give it) You can pulled​ up a loan then get all the claims that belong to it ? Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: You are correct. I was overthinking my project. I ended up deciding to go with an automatically generated key for the table because like you said this would assign a generic id to each claims since they currently don't have a number. then when I search for information regarding a specific loan it will bring up all entries that pertain to the loan number.